# How to float <li> element only without affecting another element

Tags: css, css-float

I have two divs. One should be for my menu and the second is just the title. When I try to make the `<li>` items float next to each other, it goes down from its position and affects my title div; it gets into the title div (it places itself into my title head).

HTML:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Query</li>
    <li>Reports</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <center><h3 class="empbox">Attendnace & Absence</h3></center>
```

CSS:

```
 .empbox 
 {
  height:30px;
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#6C8483 50%,#FFFFFF 100%); 
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#6C8483 50%,#FFFFFF 100%); 
  background:linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%,#6C8483 50%,#FFFFFF 100%);
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  color:White;
  margin-top:190px;
  padding-top:10px;
  }
 .menu
 {
  background:white; color:Black;
 }
 .menu ul
 {
  list-style:none;
  padding-right:20px;
 }
 .menu li 
  {
  float:left;
  }
```

I want my li to go above the title. I want to know why `<li>` is not the only element affected.  I specified `<li>` element not the entire div.

Comment: Is this what you want it to look like, can you describe in better detail? http://jsfiddle.net/watson/2HBBq/1/

Comment: What kind of details are you asking for? I don't know why was I voted down if i'm asking for help and obviously I don't have much experience to set the question clear as I don't know what is going wrong. And I want it to be above the title not below it.

Comment: You never say where you want your <li>s to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so let's do it this way... I don't know what you want actually. Can you describe it a little better? Anyhow, you don't need to float the list items. If you float the `ul` and give an `display: inline` to the `<li>`, than that should be enough. In any case, that's one problem solved. Now waiting for your response.

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/33VyN/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the title with a `<div>` that clears the float. Also `<center>` tags are deprecated.

```
<div style="text-align:center;clear:both;">
 <h3 class="empbox">Attendnace & Absence</h3>
</div>
```